# Eclipse Minecraft Modding - Game Crashed

Tags: minecraft-forge

Aqui dejo el error que me da al intentar iniciar el launcher.
Here's the code of the error that i get when i try to launch the game.

> [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Extra: []
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Running with arguments: [--userProperties, {}, --assetsDir, C:/Users/Usuario/.gradle/caches/minecraft/assets, --assetIndex, 1.12, --accessToken{REDACTED}, --version, 1.12.2, --tweakClass, >net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker, --tweakClass, net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.CoremodTweaker]
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Using primary tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.CoremodTweaker
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader version 14.23.5.2768 for Minecraft 1.12.2 loading
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [FML]: Java is Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_241, running on Windows 10:amd64:10.0, installed at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre
>   [22:42:12] [main/ERROR] [FML]: Apache Maven library folder was not in the format expected. Using default libraries directory.
>   [22:42:12] [main/ERROR] [FML]: Full: C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.maven\maven-artifact\3.5.3\7dc72b6d6d8a6dced3d294ed54c2cc3515ade9f4\maven-artifact-3.5.3.jar
>   [22:42:12] [main/ERROR] [FML]: Trimmed: c:/users/usuario/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.maven/maven-artifact/3.5.3/
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [FML]: Managed to load a deobfuscated Minecraft name- we are in a deobfuscated environment. Skipping runtime deobfuscation
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [FML]: Detected deobfuscated environment, loading log configs for colored console logs.
>   2020-03-10 22:42:12,738 main WARN Disabling terminal, you're running in an unsupported environment.
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [FML]: Ignoring missing certificate for coremod FMLCorePlugin (net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.FMLCorePlugin), we are in deobf and it's a forge core plugin
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [FML]: Ignoring missing certificate for coremod FMLForgePlugin (net.minecraftforge.classloading.FMLForgePlugin), we are in deobf and it's a forge core plugin
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [FML]: Searching C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Minecraft Mod\EndRPGMod\run.\mods for mods
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.CoremodTweaker
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Injecting location in coremod net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.FMLCorePlugin
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Injecting location in coremod net.minecraftforge.classloading.FMLForgePlugin
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.AccessTransformerTweaker
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
>   [22:42:12] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
>   [22:42:13] [main/ERROR] [FML]: FML appears to be missing any signature data. This is not a good thing
>   [22:42:13] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
>   [22:42:13] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
>   [22:42:13] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.AccessTransformerTweaker
>   [22:42:13] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.TerminalTweaker
>   [22:42:13] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.TerminalTweaker
>   [22:42:13] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Launching wrapped minecraft {net.minecraft.client.main.Main}
>   [22:42:14] [main/INFO] [minecraft/Minecraft]: Setting user: Player60
>   [22:42:15] [main/WARN] [minecraft/GameSettings]: Skipping bad option: lastServer:
>   [22:42:15] [main/INFO] [minecraft/Minecraft]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
>   [22:42:16] [main/INFO] [FML]: -- System Details --
>   Details:
>       Minecraft Version: 1.12.2
>       Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
>       Java Version: 1.8.0_241, Oracle Corporation
>       Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
>       Memory: 595476864 bytes (567 MB) / 758120448 bytes (723 MB) up to 7624720384 bytes (7271 MB)
>       JVM Flags: 0 total; 
>       IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
>       FML: 
>       Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
>       GL info: ' Vendor: 'NVIDIA Corporation' Version: '4.6.0 NVIDIA 442.19' Renderer: 'GeForce RTX 2060/PCIe/SSE2'
>   [22:42:16] [main/INFO] [FML]: MinecraftForge v14.23.5.2768 Initialized
>   [22:42:16] [main/INFO] [FML]: Starts to replace vanilla recipe ingredients with ore ingredients.
>   [22:42:16] [main/INFO] [FML]: Replaced 1036 ore ingredients
>   [22:42:16] [main/INFO] [FML]: Searching C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Minecraft Mod\EndRPGMod\run.\mods for mods
>   [22:42:17] [main/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader has identified 5 mods to load
>   [22:42:17] [main/INFO] [FML]: Attempting connection with missing mods [minecraft, mcp, FML, forge, erpgm] at CLIENT
>   [22:42:17] [main/INFO] [FML]: Attempting connection with missing mods [minecraft, mcp, FML, forge, erpgm] at SERVER
>   [22:42:18] [main/ERROR] [FML]: An error occurred trying to load a proxy into proxy.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ghozix.enderpgmod.proxy.ClientProxy
>   [22:42:18] [main/INFO] [STDOUT]: [net.minecraft.init.Bootstrap:printToSYSOUT:629]: ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
>   // Daisy, daisy...
>
> Time: 3/10/20 10:42 PM
>   Description: There was a severe problem during mod loading that has caused the game to fail
>
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoaderException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ghozix.enderpgmod.proxy.ClientProxy
>       at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.ProxyInjector.inject(ProxyInjector.java:102)
>       at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:600)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
>       at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
>       at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
>       at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
>       at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
>       at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
>       at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:218)
>       at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:196)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
>       at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
>       at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
>       at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
>       at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
>       at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
>       at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:135)
>       at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:593)
>       at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:232)
>       at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:513)
>       at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:421)
>       at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
>       at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97)
>       at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:25)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ghozix.enderpgmod.proxy.ClientProxy
>       at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:191)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
>       at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.ModClassLoader.loadClass(ModClassLoader.java:75)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>       at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.ProxyInjector.inject(ProxyInjector.java:85)
>       ... 43 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182)
>       ... 49 more

### A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

> -- System Details --
>   Details:
>       Minecraft Version: 1.12.2
>       Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
>       Java Version: 1.8.0_241, Oracle Corporation
>       Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
>       Memory: 834373248 bytes (795 MB) / 1197473792 bytes (1142 MB) up to 7624720384 bytes (7271 MB)
>       JVM Flags: 0 total; 
>       IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
>       FML: MCP 9.42 Powered by Forge 14.23.5.2768 5 mods loaded, 5 mods active
>       States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored

```
| State | ID        | Version      | Source                           | Signature |
|:----- |:--------- |:------------ |:-------------------------------- |:--------- |
| UC    | minecraft | 1.12.2       | minecraft.jar                    | None      |
| UC    | mcp       | 9.42         | minecraft.jar                    | None      |
| UC    | FML       | 8.0.99.99    | forgeSrc-1.12.2-14.23.5.2768.jar | None      |
| UC    | forge     | 14.23.5.2768 | forgeSrc-1.12.2-14.23.5.2768.jar | None      |
| UE    | erpgm     | 1.0.0        | bin                              | None      |

Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
GL info: ' Vendor: 'NVIDIA Corporation' Version: '4.6.0 NVIDIA 442.19' Renderer: 'GeForce RTX 2060/PCIe/SSE2'
```

> [22:42:18] [main/INFO] [STDOUT]: [net.minecraft.init.Bootstrap:printToSYSOUT:629]: #@!@# Game crashed! Crash report saved to: #@!@# C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Minecraft Mod\EndRPGMod\run.\crash-reports\crash-2020-03-10_22.42.18-client.txt

Comment: y qué se supone que falla?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] por favor visita https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para hacer preguntas que sean bien acogidas por la comunidad

Comment: Pues sencillamente que a la hora de hacer el "Run" no me ejecuta, el juego Crashea y pues he copiado todo el texto dónde esta el error para ver si así alguien puede averiguar el por qué me crashea.

Comment: Minecraft es un juego y marca comercial; y lo que intentas hacer no es legal, esta relacionado al cracking/mod de jugos sin licencias... principalmente por esto: ***minecraft-forge***